# post method not allowed to this route in laravel 7.30.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have this error in my web application:

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

but i don´t understand where are my problem because, my route:list comand return this:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | calendario                                 | calendario.index         | App\Http\Controllers\EventController@index                             | web        |
|        | POST      | calendario                                 | calendario.store         | App\Http\Controllers\EventController@store                             | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | calendario/create                          | calendario.create        | App\Http\Controllers\EventController@create                            | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | calendario/{calendario}                    | calendario.show          | App\Http\Controllers\EventController@show                              | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | calendario/{calendario}                    | calendario.update        | App\Http\Controllers\EventController@update                            | web        |
|        | DELETE    | calendario/{calendario}                    | calendario.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\EventController@destroy                           | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | calendario/{calendario}/edit               | calendario.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\EventController@edit                              | web        |
```

i want to create event in my full calendar using a route::resource.

my route:

```
Route::resource('calendario', 'EventController');
```

and in my view i have a check for to know in that route i´m if edit, store or show:

```
<form action="{{ Request::is('calendario/*/edit') ? route('calendario.update', $event->id) : route('calendario.create') }}" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    @if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'calendario.edit')
                        @method('PUT') 
                    @endif
```

in my web browser console i have a correct route:

```
<form action="http://www.clinicacampoy.local/calendario/create" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="rVb2ycSugwg0weAbZucdI8RzBi9uT7QumGArJOOW">

                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Nombre del cliente">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fecha-inicio">Fecha-hora Inicio</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha-inicio">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fecha-inicio">Fecha-hora fin</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha-fin">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Crear Cita">
                </form>
```

but return this error and i don´t know that i´m doin wrong. In my controler for this moment i have a `echo` for to know that i´m arrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `store` instead of `create` in `route('calendario.create')`.

`create` method is a get method that is responsible for making creating **view**. the storage logic should be in store method.
If you want to use `Route::resource` though.